oauth2 with google not working in docker container
i have a microservice for logging in using oauth2. it gets a login request from the frontend that is routed through a gateway.
the service works just fine when i run it normally using mvn spring-boot:run
but when running it in a docker container the login page cant be reached. i dont understand why.
the services security config
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**", "/api/login/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/google")
                        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());               // Disable CSRF if needed

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:8000")); // Allow specific origins
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")); // Allow specific methods
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type", "Accept")); // Allow specific headers
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true); // Allow credentials like cookies

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); // Apply CORS settings to all endpoints
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
                OidcUser oidcUser = (OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
                request.getSession().setAttribute("user", oidcUser);
                System.out.println("User details: " + oidcUser.getAttributes());
                response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:3000/");
            }
        };
    }
}

the logincontroller looks like this
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/api/login/oauth2/code/google")
    public ResponseEntity<String> callback(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token, HttpServletRequest request) {



        // Print request details
        System.out.println("Request Method: " + request.getMethod());
        System.out.println("Request URL: " + request.getRequestURL());
        System.out.println("Request Headers: ");
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println(headerName + ": " + request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
        if (token == null) {
            System.out.println("Authentication token is missing or invalid.");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Authentication token is missing or invalid.");
        }

        OAuth2User user = token.getPrincipal();
        String email = user.getAttribute("email");
        String name = user.getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println("User details: " + user.getAttributes());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Welcome, " + name + " (" + email + ")");
    }
}

i have tried changing the routing to go directly to the service and not do any load balancing but i got the same result. i am very confused as to what the difference between running it in a docker container and running it normally is so it is hard for me to troubleshoot

À frequent cause for misconfiguration In Docker is that localhost refers to the container itself and not the host machine (you can't reach the authorization server from a Spring app in a container with "localhost" in properties). You should read that: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak
